# Output IP adress and Hostname to config file

Tags: batch-file, output

Not very well versed in writing batch files, but i'm looking for a way to create a batch file to be run on a windows machine when run adds the hostname and local ip adress to a specific line in a config file.

The output would be :

line 54= SourceIP=192.168.x.x

line 140= Hostname=computername

is there anyone that can point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Batch will only append text to the end of a text file. You can load the script to string (Depending on size as batch string is limited) and use syntax-replace to edit parts of the text then offload to a new file. A better alternative for this would be powershell.

Comment: @DavidPostill, +1 for your friendly tone